# Github pull request template for a specific branch

Tags: github, pull-request

Is it possible to assign a pull request template for a specific branch? Is using query parameters the only work around?

Answer (score 4):

[Query parameters](https://help.github.com/articles/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters/) are recommended.

As mentioned in "[About PR templates](https://help.github.com/articles/about-issue-and-pull-request-templates/#pull-request-templates)":

> You must create templates on the repository's default branch.
> Templates created in other branches are not available for collaborators to use.

---

An alternative approach, available more recently (2021+), would be to use a GitHub Action like [`actions/pull-request-updater-github-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pull-request-updater-github-action), which can updates a pull request with information extracted from branch name.

```yaml
name: "Update Pull Request"
on: pull_request

jobs:
  update_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: tzkhan/pr-update-action@v2
      with:
        repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        base-branch-regex: '[a-z\d-_.\\/]+'
        head-branch-regex: 'foo-\d+'
        title-template: '[%headbranch%] '
        body-template: |
          Merging into '%basebranch%'
          [Link to %headbranch%](https://url/to/browse/ticket/%headbranch%)
        body-update-action: 'suffix'
        body-uppercase-base-match: false
```

[image: https://github.com/tzkhan/pr-update-action/raw/master/img/pr-after.png]

This is not *exactly* a template per branch, but you could fork this action and modify it in order to seek a template file per branch, and replace the body of the PR with it.

Comment: the article you linked to is only talking about issue creating templates. the question here is about PR templates and doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @LilithSchneider I agree. Since my 2018 answer, I would now use a GitHub Action to do that. I have edited the answer accordingly.