# Github branch specific pull request template

Tags: github, pull-request

I was wondering if it is possible to create a branch specific pull request template just like I see we have in [Azure Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates?view=azure-devops#branch-specific-pull-request-templates).

The only thing I could find is global templates for the whole repo but nothing about specific branches.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github pull request template for a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698118/github-pull-request-template-for-a-specific-branch)